# Spinning arrow animation on Toolbar not working on first call

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

I have `MainActivity`, `FragmentA` and a lower-level fragment `FragmentB`. That means that, when in `FragmentB`, I want to:

- Disable the drawer;
- Make the drawer icon spin into the Up arrow.

It all works fine. In `FragmentB` I'm calling:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).openLowLevelFragment();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).closeLowLevelFragment();
}
```

And in my activity I have:

```
public void openLowLevelFragment() {
    animateArrow(0f, 1f);
    mT.setNavigationOnClickListener(...);
    mDL.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
}

public void closeLowLevelFragment() {
    animateArrow(1f, 0f);
    mT.setNavigationOnClickListener(...);
    mDL.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
}
```

where `animateArrow()` is the method I use to switch between the burger icon and the arrow, using `ActionBarDrawerToggle.onDrawerSlide()`. This works totally fine, like:

- `FragmentA -> FragmentB` : icon spins to arrow;
- `FragmentB -> FragmentA` : arrow spins back to drawer icon;

What is wrong is that *on the first time* I go to `FragmentB`, the animation is *not working*, i.e. I see the burger icon going to its last state (the arrow) without animating. Why is it? What can I do?

I'll post my value animator here. Thanks for help.

```
public void animateArrow(float start, float end) {
    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(start, end);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float slideOffset = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            mABDT.onDrawerSlide(mDL, slideOffset);
        }
    });
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(250);
    anim.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with animation has completed before the UI is rendered. The animation will occur on the view without a layout, so check if the layout of the view (Fragment B in your case) is rendered before the animation.

Comment: Do you see any workaround? Plus, why would it work the second time (A->B), when the first instance of B already went through `onDestroy()` ?